# I have a multiple request coming from XML and each request I need to process and send back the response to the user IN JAXB class as LIST

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

The request will be in the form of Alphanumeric characters.
For example the below request : for ID tag I need to pass this ID to database and process which will be call to Database for generating response and store it into JAXB class in LIST format.
I understand that I need to take the list of ID and iterate as a single request

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LISTREQUEST>
<ID><WSDKJ554555244dfs></ID>
<ID><WSDKJ554555244dfs></ID>
<ID><WSDKJ554555244dfs></ID>
</LISTREQUEST>
```

Can someone provide me the logic in JAVA to implement for above XML request

PFB code example, here LISTREQUEST is JAXB class from XSD

```java
LISTREQUEST ids= new LISTREQUEST();
Object [] id=ids.getID();
for(String list:id){
```

Let me know what logic here I can use in JAVA to get a single ID and process it, next take the second ID and process the same ... which will get store into an JAXB class for sending response.

Comment: That isn't well-formed xml.

Comment: I had just given an example of ID's coming in request in LIST of object which are need to process

Answer (score 0):

In below format I have a JAXB class

```
public class Lists {
    // ...
    protected List<Integer> numbers;
    // ...
    public List<Integer> getID() {
        if (numbers == null) {
            numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        return this.numbers;
    }
    // ...
}
```